# Quadratic residue modulo with prime p exponent of two

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have a situation:
They give me a `c` and a `p` with conditions below:

- c ≡ $m^2$ mod $p^2$
- p is a prime and p ≡ 1 mod 4
- 1 < m < $p^2$

Find `m`.
I tried use extended Euclidean algorithm to find it but I couldn't found anything for this situation. Please help me!

Comment: You can use nearly arbitrary values for that for example: c=4, m=2, p=5 or c=9, m=3, p=5 or c=16, m=4, p=13

Comment: @Etoplay I dont get your point.

Comment: There are infinite many solutions. Just take a prime p with $p = 1 \mod 4$, a $m$ with $m<p$ and $c=m^2$

Comment: @Etoplay I can't do it with brute force because my p length is 2048 bits

Answer (score 1):

(For the original version, where $m \lt p$ was imposed, then $m^2 < p^2$ thus for $c$ to be *congruent to* $m^2$ modulo $p^2$ they need to be *equal* as integers.

Thus, you compute the square-root of $c$ as an integer and are done.)

Now, for the general problem of finding roots modulo primes and powers of primes,   ["Tonelli-Shanks"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) and ["Cippola"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipolla%27s_algorithm) are standard algorithms for the prime case. Then ["lift" using "Hensel."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma)

See ["Is there an efficient algorithm for finding a square root modulo a prime power?"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52081/is-there-an-efficient-algorithm-for-finding-a-square-root-modulo-a-prime-power) on MathOverflow for further details.

Comment: I'm so sorry I made a mistake. m < $p^2$

Comment: I added a little more info to my answer.